# Word that implies membership to multiple organizations/associations

Tags: word-choice

When an individual belongs to an organization, they can be said to be a **member** of that organization. From the organization's perspective, they may have 1 or more **members** who have joined their organization. So the word that means *all the individuals who belong to them* is simply **members**.

However, the individual may of course belong to *many* different organizations. I am looking for a word that correctly describes *all the organizations an individual belongs to*.

In other words:

- Jane is a member of Org A, Org B and Org D
- John is a member of Org B
- Jack is a member of Org B and Org C

Given those memberships above:

- Org A's **member(s)** are: Jane
- Org B's **member(s)** are: Jane, John and Jack
- Org C's **member(s)** are: Jack
- Org D's **member(s)** are: Jane

I'm looking for the word that describes all the orgs that a particular individual is a member of, so:

- Jane's **???** is: Org A, Org B and Org D
- John's **???** is: Org B
- Jack's **???** is: Org B and Org C

**I'm looking for a single word that exists in both single and plural form (member/members, etc.)**, not something like "*is a member of*", etc. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Jane's **affiliations are**: Org A, Org B and Org D*

*Jane's **associations are**: Org A, Org B and Org D*

*Jane's **memberships are**: Org A, Org B and Org D*